# Missing Kafka source/sink in springcloud

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to use Kafka Source/Sink in SpringCloud Dataflow but I cannot find thes app-starters in spring-cloud-stream-app-starters.
They were available in Spring XD. Does anyone knows why they disappeared ?

Thanks

Comment: You can find them here: source- > https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/source and sink-> https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/sink .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [named destination](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-explicit-destination-names) as the source/sink and set `headerMode=raw` if the producer (for a source) or consumer (for a sink) is not a Spring Cloud Stream app.

```
dataflow:>stream create foo --definition ":myTopic > log --inputType=text/plain"

dataflow:>stream deploy --name foo --properties app.log.consumer.headerMode=raw
```